# Drupal 7 jCarousel Views and How to add title as caption to slide

Tags: view, drupal-7, field, jcarousel

I have a jCarousel block that uses a view that is formatted to show 'Content' from a 'Search result'. I have been trying to configure the view so that an image title is displayed beneath the carousel slide.

The carousel view is formatted to Show: 'Content' by 'Search result'. I have 'force using fields' enabled and 'Content:Title' is listed under the Fields section.

The 'Content type' I'm using, Gallery Image, is based-on the Image type and has the default 'title' field (Node module element field). However, there are no Manage Display options for the 'title' field - have I done something wrong?

Please do let me know if there are any additional details I should post.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide some pointers.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display the title as a caption is to change the "Format > Show setting" from "Content" to "Fields".

Under your view settings tab:

Format
Format: jCarousel | Settings
Show: **Fields** | Settings